# explode data in codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

this is my code to display filters using explode function

```
 <?php    if($a_row->a_filters !=''){
      $filters = explode(',', $a_row->a_filters);
      foreach ($filters as $filter_row):   $arr = explode("/", $filter_row, 2);   ?>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
       <span><strong><?php echo $arr[0]; ?></strong> :</span> <?php echo $arr[1]; ?>
      </div>
       <?php   endforeach; }   ?>
```

this code display result like this

Fixture-Colour : Nickel    Fixture-Colour : Crome   Fixture-Colour : Black Fixture-Colour : Branze    Fixture-Colour : Brown   Fixture-Colour : Copper Fixture-Colour : Clear     Fixture-Colour : Greay   Fixture-Colour : Multi-colour 
Fixture-Colour : Red       Fixture-Colour : White   Fixture-Colour : Yellow Fixture-Colour : Blue      Fixture-Colour : Green   Fixture-Colour : Violet Fixture-Colour : Orange    Fixture-Colour : Gold    Fixture-Colour : Silver Fixture-Colour : Texture   Glass-Colour : Brown     Glass-Colour : Grey Glass-Colour : Multi-colour Glass-Colour : Red      Glass-Colour : White Glass-Colour : Yellow       Glass-Colour : Blue     Glass-Colour : Green Glass-Colour : Violet       Glass-Colour : Orange   Shape : Cone 
Shape : Cylinder            Shape : Drum            Shape : Linear 
Shape : Round               Shape : Square          Shape : Other

but i want to display result like this using implode or explode

Fixture-Colour : Nickel, Crome, Black, Branze , Brown , Copper , Clear, Greay, Multi-colour , Red , White, Yellow , Blue , Green , Violet , Orange    ,Gold ,Silver , Texture

Glass-Colour : Brown ,Grey , Multi-colour , Red  , White ,Yellow       , Blue  , Green , Violet  , Orange

Shape : Cone , Cylinder , Drum ,Linear ,Round, Square , Other

Comment: Can you share the query?

Comment: add result of this in question `print_r($a_row->a_filters)`.

Comment: In mysql database  a_filters column values store in this format   :   Fixture-Colour/Nickel, Fixture-Colour/Crome, Fixture-Colour/Black, Fixture-Colour/Green, Fixture-Colour/Violet, Fixture-Colour/Orange, Fixture-Colour/Gold, Fixture-Colour/Silver, Fixture-Colour/Texture, Glass-Colour/Brown, Glass-Colour/Grey, Glass-Colour/Blue, Glass-Colour/Green, Glass-Colour/Violet, Glass-Colour/Orange, Shape/Cone, Shape/Cylinder, Shape/Drum, Shape/Linear, Shape/Round, Shape/Square, Shape/Other

Comment: but i want to separate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text="Fixture-Colour/Nickel,Fixture-Colour/Crome,Fixture-Colour/Black,Fixture-Colour/Branze,Fixture-Colour/Brown,Fixture-Colour/Copper,Fixture-Colour/Clear,Fixture-Colour/Greay,Fixture-Colour/Multi-colour,Fixture-Colour/Red,Fixture-Colour/White,Fixture-Colour/Yellow,Fixture-Colour/Blue,Fixture-Colour/Green,Fixture-Colour/Violet,Fixture-Colour/Orange,Fixture-Colour/Gold,Fixture-Colour/Silver,Fixture-Colour/Texture,Glass-Colour/Brown,Glass-Colour/Grey,Glass-Colour/Orange,Glass-Colour/Multi-colour,Glass-Colour/Red,Glass-Colour/White,Glass-Colour/Yellow,Glass-Colour/Blue,Glass-Colour/Green,Glass-Colour/Violet,Glass-Colour/Orange,Shape/Cone,Shape/Cylinder,Shape/Drum,Shape/Linear,Shape/Round,Shape/Square,Shape/Other";

$filters = explode(',', $text);

/*For re-grouping the array */
foreach($filters as $filter_row){
    $arr = explode("/", $filter_row, 2);
    $new_array[$arr[0]][] = $arr[1];
}

/*Generating your expected output*/
foreach ($new_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.": ".implode(', ', $value);
    echo "<br />";
}
```